# C# Basic web HttpWebRequest, does not support Javascript

Tags: c#, javascript

I have a basic C# HttpWebRequest. My problem is the page that it is sending the GET request to, requires javascript (on the client-side) to be enabled for the content to generate.

How can I add javascript support to my code? Is it even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HttpWebRequest just implements GET, you need full browser to execute JavaScript (and possibly need CSS files to as scripts may depend on them).

The built in approach is to use [WebBrowser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.aspx) control to render pages, that grab innerHTML after you find that JavaScript rendering is done.

Answer (score 4):

The server can't really know whether the client supports Javascript. It can only go on the data you give it.

So there are two possibilities:

- It's using headers to work out what response to send, and *inferring* that you can't run Javascript. Solution: work out what headers it requires, and set them explicitly.
- It's sending you back the page, but you're unable to use it because you're not displaying it on a browser. Solution: look at the page, work out what AJAX calls the Javascript is making, and make those instead. You may not even need to fetch the original hosting page.