# PhantomJS- open page with LocalStorage by default

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, local-storage

I'm using [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) to get the generated source of a web page after JavaScript DOM manipulations have taken place. This web page has JUST a `<body>` and nothing else.

***Important***: This web page uses browser's `localStorage` to generate the page.

I want to change LocalStorage in PhantomJS before opening the page.

**App.js**:

```
var page = require('webpage').create();

page.open("https://sample.com")
setTimeout(function(){
    // Where you want to save it    
    page.render("screenshoot.png")  
    // You can access its content using jQuery
    var fbcomments = page.evaluate(function(){
        return $("body").contents().find(".content") 
    }) 
    phantom.exit();
}, 1000)
```

Comment: You can set some `localStorage` property inside of `page.evaluate()`. Have you tried it? What's the issue?

Comment: @ArtjomB. thanks for edit and comment. My issue is set localstorage for browser before **page.open(url)**

Comment: How can you set localStorage for a page you have not visited yet?

Comment: @ArtjomB. thanks for edit

Comment: @epascarello I am trying this to set localStorage for a page before open.

Comment: But how can you set something before you visit the page? You need to load up that domain once, set the storage.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

localStorage for a particular domain is only available when you open a page on that domain. You can

1. open some URL on the domain you're interested in,
2. change `localStorage` according to your needs,
3. open your target URL on the same domain.

This can look like this:

```
page.open("https://sample.com/asdfasdf", function(){
    page.evaluate(function(){
        localStorage.setItem("something", "whatever");
    });

    page.open("https://sample.com", function(){
        setTimeout(function(){
            // Where you want to save it    
            page.render("screenshoot.png")  
            // You can access its content using jQuery
            var fbcomments = page.evaluate(function(){
                return $("body").contents().find(".content") 
            }) 
            phantom.exit();
        },1000)
    });    
});
```

It's also possible not to open a full page in step 1. You can also use dummy page with some URL.

```
page.setContent("", "https://sample.com"); // doesn't actually open any page

page.evaluate(function(){
    localStorage.setItem("something", "whatever");
});

page.open("https://sample.com", function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        // Where you want to save it    
        page.render("screenshoot.png")  
        // You can access its content using jQuery
        var fbcomments = page.evaluate(function(){
            return $("body").contents().find(".content") 
        }) 
        phantom.exit();
    }, 1000)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem with Friend's Help. My solution is:

> Notice: I set Timeout 10000(10 seconds) for complete load page.

```
var page = require('webpage').create();

page.open("https://sample.com", function(){
    page.evaluate(function(){
        var i = 0,
        oJson = jsonData,
        sKey;
        localStorage.clear();

        for (; sKey = Object.keys(oJson)[i]; i++) {
            localStorage.setItem(sKey,oJson[sKey])
        }
    });

    page.open("https://sample.com", function(){
        setTimeout(function(){
         page.render("screenshoot.png") 
            // Where you want to save it    
           console.log(page.content); //page source
            // You can access its content using jQuery
            var fbcomments = page.evaluate(function(){
                return $("body").contents().find(".content") 
            }) 
            phantom.exit();
        },10000)
    });    
});
```